# Random number between 0 and textbox text

Tags: swift, random

So I want to generate a random number between 0 and numberTextBox.text.

Let's say that the textbox text is 5, then i want to generate a random number between 0 and 5.

I have now:

```
@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {
let maxInteger = MacNumber.toInt()!
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxNumber));
let mxNumber = numberTextBox.text

var textString = String(randomNumber)
numberLabel.text = textString
}
```

But when I test the application, and type 5 in the textBox, the numberLabel.text is something like 192819371.. It's very high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if numberTextbox.text == ""{
            return
        }
            var number:Int = 1 + numberTextbox.text.toInt()!
            var randomNumber = random() % number

        if randomNumber == 0{
            randomNumber = 1
        }

        var textString = String(randomNumber)
            numberLabel.text = textString
    }
```

I also added that if the textbox is empty, it just returns, and if the randomNumber is 0, it goes to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use random(), use `arc4random()` or `arc4random_uniform()`. `random()` needs to be seeded and will return the same sequence for the same seed after every seeding.

```
let maxInteger = MaxNumber.toInt()!
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxNumber));
```

`arc4random()` does not need to be seeded and returns cryptographic quality random numbers.
Use `arc4random_uniform()` when the range needs to be constrained instead of the modulus operate `%` to eliminate modulo bias.

See: [ARC4RANDOM(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html)

Comment: I get error message:Cannot invoke "arc4random_uniform" with an argument list of type "(String")

Comment: Because numberTextBox.text is a string, not a number, parse it to integer with `toInt()`

Comment: @riodoro1 - Yes, I have already don't that, and still get error: Cannot find an initializer for type "UInt32" that accepts an argument list fo type "(String)"

Comment: Do some debugging. Put a breakpoint in the code, single step through the code and watch the values to see what is going on. Or add `println()` statements after every statement to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a random number in Swift, use the arc4random_uniform() function. The following code snippet generates a number from 0 to 9:

```
var i = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you should try `let randomNumber = random() % MaxNumber` 
instead of 
`let randomNumber = random(); MaxNumber` ?

Comment: Do not use random(), use arc4random or arc4random_uniform(). random() needs to be seeded and will return the same sequence for the same seed every run.